# Disable auto resize of custom button groups in the Ribbon

Tags: vsto, office-interop, ribbon-control, office-2013, ribbonx

We have an office addin which adds groups of buttons in the Ribbon. Recently I upgraded from office 2007 to 2013 and the addin seemed to work all well. The only thing i noticed is a bit of a behaviour change in the buttons at small screen resolutions.

In 2007, no  matter how small the window was, the custom button groups I add to the window don't resize/collapse into one button. However in 2013 these same groups seem to eventually collapse into one drop down button.

Is there any way to force it to remain it's full size in 2013 as it does in 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Office 2010 you may enable auto-scaling by setting the `autoScale` attribute of the  tag to True as follows.

```
autoScale="true"
```

Note, auto-scaling is set on a per-group basis.

See [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691834(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure if this does what I'm after? It seems like autoscale will eventually get to the point where the group collapses when the screens small enough. I want it to never collapse. In 2007 my groups never collapsed, the tab just became horizontally scrollable when it got too big (some of the inbuilt groups collapse but my custom ones never did) . Even in 2013 it seems some groups never collapse, but I can't detect what stops them from collapsing.

Comment: The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that except the `autoScale` tag.